# spotify filtering title

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm building a personal app within the Spotiy framework. I'm having issues with track and artist titles that have special special characters like single/double quotes, ampersands and so forth...

While digging for solutions I found hack using the replace() method. But then doing a little more digging, I found a sample code from Spotify itself, and noticed something strange. Essentially when the sample code collected the track info and then displayed it within the innerHTML property of a

tag, the track title displayed the special characters properly, but when I tried displaying the info within say an alert() or as a value into a text box, the title came out with the special characters messed up.

Again, I can use the replace() method to fix this, but I'm curious to know why this behavior is happening (aka innerHTML displaying correct vs. alerts and text boxes being wrong).

Here's the code I used:

http://codetidy.com/3891/

EDIT:

From what I read it looks like innerHTML does in fact encode special characters into common web forms. But since I'm placing values into a text box, I made my own filter:

http://codetidy.com/3892/

Answer (score 0):

First, read up on HTML encoding and (for instance) the difference between innerHTML and innerText (and also the XSS security implications of not handling the difference between these two correctly!)

Now, the Spotify Api (at least the one within the Spotify app; the web API works differently) returns the values by default HTML encoded.

If you are sure you want the Text encoding of a string, use the decodeForText() method on the string (so `var textname = data.name.decodeForText();`).

Also see the [Spotify documentation on this issue](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/integration/#encodedstrings).